# How to get the method GetCustomAttribute from MemberInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection

I try to do some reflection on some types.

So I have this

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [MethodForRun(RunCount = 3)]
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{FirstName} {LastName}");
        }


        [MethodForRun(RunCount =2)]
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello THere {FirstName}");
        }

        static void AttributeTest(Type type)
        {
            var allMethods = type.GetMethods();
            var methodWithAttributes = allMethods.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MethodForRunAttribute)) != null);
        }
    }

    public class MethodForRunAttribute:Attribute
    {
        public int RunCount { get; set; }
    }
```

And it is about the method AttributeTest.

I just can't do

```
x.GetCustomAttribute
```

I only can do GetCustomAttributes - so plural. But not just GetCustomAttribute.

```
rror    CS1061  'MethodInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute' and no accessible extension method 'GetCustomAttribute' accepting a first argument of type 'MethodInfo' could be found
```

What I have to change?

Thank you

And the Library

Comment: You want to use it like this: `Where( e => Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(e, typeof(MethodForRunAttribute)))` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattribute?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Yes, But I can;t do  x.GetCustomAttribute. I am using .NET 5.0

Answer (score 0):

??

```
using System.Reflection;
```

I had this namespace. But It was not using it. So I added again. And now it works.